# Xamarin - Not allowed to start service intent

Tags: c#, xamarin, onesignal

Hi so i'm a total newbie to android development.
I'm working with OneSignal to send push notifications to my android phone. 
The android version i'm running is 8.0

The errors I received:
In VS it says 'Not allowed to start service intent'
In the android phone it says 'Failed to post notification on channel null'

So my code is pretty simple, I have only messed with the `AndroidManifest.xml` , `App.xaml.cs`

`AndroidManifest.xml` Code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.theoctant.onesignalsample" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<permission android:name="com.theoctant.onesignalsample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.theoctant.onesignalsample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application android:label="OneSignalSample.Android">
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.theoctant.onesignalsample" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application> </manifest>
```

As for `App.xaml.cs`, I've only entered about 1 line of code and that's for the API keys. So i don't think the problem lies there...